# Safari: CSS Multi-column hover bug with absolute position?

Tags: html, css, safari, css-multicolumn-layout

I have the following easy CSS Multi-column layout:

```css
ul {
  column-count: 3;
}

li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  bottom: 0;
  color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
  transition: top .25s ease-in-out;
}

li:hover .hover {
  top: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img src="https://picsum.photos/400/50" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="https://picsum.photos/400/100" alt=""></li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/300" alt="">
    <div class="hover">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you hover over the third item, the hover `div` should have the same size as the third list element and exactly on the same position. This works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

However, in Safari, the hover `div` will also be in the first column after the first two images.

A comparison:

**Chrome:**

[image: Chrome Grid Hover]

**Safari:**

[image: Safari Grid Hover]

Is there anything I am missing or is this just a bug in Safari?

I’m running the latest version of both browsers (Chrome 65.0.3325.146 and Safari 11.0.3).

Comment: intresting, by they way what if you try 0% instead of 0 ? [it should be the same but we never know]

Comment: Is this an example of absolute position not respecting grid tracks?

Comment: No...there's no Grid involved here at all despite the title.

Comment: I corrected the post title to avoid the confusions there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below, in general it's a trick to prevents column items to break.

```
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
ul {
  column-count: 3;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  bottom: 0;
  color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
  transition: top .25s ease-in-out;
}

li:hover .hover {
  top: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x50" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x100" alt=""></li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x300" alt="">
    <div class="hover">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```